# Java: PrintWriter object does not output the text on my file?

Tags: java, file, printwriter

I'm trying to print out the usernames of a certain program into a file but PrintWriter is not printing anything on my file. I've tried everything mentioned on stackOverFlow none of them worked.

**Users Class**

```
private File usersListFile;
private PrintWriter usersListPrintWriter;
private Scanner usersListScanner;
```

**Constructor:**

```
Users(){
    try {
        this.usersListFile = new File("D:\\Dairy\\usersList.txt");
        if(usersListFile.exists()){
            this.usersListPrintWriter = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("D:\\Dairy\\usersList.txt", true)));
            this.usersListScanner = new Scanner("D:\\Dairy\\usersList.txt");
        }
        else
            System.err.println("File does not exist !");
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.err.println("Error: Users Class!");                   
    }
}
```

**Method:**

```
public void addToUsersList(String username){
        usersListPrintWriter.print(username);           
    }
```

**Main Method:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Users usersObject = new Users();
    usersObject.addToUsersList("USERNAME");

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`usersListPrintWriter` is buffered, so you need to flush the data (as Alexandro mentioned too).

You also likely will need to change the `print` into a `println` so newly added users are output on separate lines.

Your `Scanner` will not work, since you're scanning the given string, not the file content. Use `new Scanner(this.usersListFile)` instead.

You should also re-use your `File` object on the previous line: `new FileWriter(this.usersListFile, true)`

And I would say that having a `Writer` and a `Scanner` open on the same file at the same time is a bad idea, if it even works. You should probably just load all the users into memory and close the scanner before opening the writer, unless you have

Comment: You are awesome! I was wondering what's wrong with my Scanner, Thank you very much!

Comment: @EJP I deliberately referred to `usersListPrintWriter`, not `PrintWriter`, since `usersListPrintWriter` is explicitly created with a `BufferedWriter` in the chain. You are however correct in implying that `PrinWriter` is also buffering, and so is `FileWriter` I believe. Changing answer back.

Comment: n that case it would be better to say 'both `PrintWriter` and `BufferedWriter` are buffered' in the answer. Variables aren't buffered.

Answer (score 1):

```
public void addToUsersList(String username){
    usersListPrintWriter.print(username);           
    usersListPrintWriter.flush();
}
```

Then, when you don't need anymore your printwriter, call `close()`.